# Issues (auto) closed and re-open

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

Dear SonarQube Development team and other experts,

I use SonarQube 5.3 and MSBuild Runner.

A few weeks ago, I experienced issues when closing the program. These issues persisted even when leaving a file unchanged.

Furthermore, these issues may be oustide the range of 1000 lines.

I'm working on improving myself thanks especially to SonarQube.

Currently, I eagerly await the next release, because:

- The next release has promised to fix among other things, the 1000 line restriction.
- My hope is that another issue called, the sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria will be fixed too.

Since yesterday, we have installed the latest versions of Sprint and SonarQube.

By the evening, we experienced many additional file issues, where they had changed, but not in-line with the issues raised.

In the previous week, I updated the C# plugin. Doing this added 11000 issues from already active rules. These issues are primarilly from, 'Fxcop'.

For now, we can't trust the 'technical debt' on Sprint.

Comment: The problem is come back. We lost 19k issues in only one analysis. When we look on files, the issues are not resolved and files are not modified. Is it beacause the issues are not ine a confirmed state ?
If we modifiy one of theses files, the issues are re-created for the file modified.