# sonar issue auto closed and reopen

Tags: c#, sonarqube, fxcop, stylecop

Here is the context, I use

1. Sonar 5.6.1
2. C# plugin 5.4.0.464
3. StyleCop plugin 1.1

We have **many issues that are automatically closed and reopen** during a Sonar analysis. This problem arrive even if the analyzed file has not been modified.

In each of the following case I check, the result is "issues are closed, reopen, and reassigned to the previous developer":

1. Unassigned or assigned manually
2. Tag/Untag issues
3. Remove Sonar project

Please can you help us?

Note: I have already seen this post [Issues (auto) closed and re-open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574738/issues-auto-closed-and-re-open), there is no answer and i **use a different version of sonar and C# plugin**

### EDIT

I have just upgrade the solution and the bug is always here. Here is my configuration:

- Sonar 5.6.6
- C# plugin 5.7.0.612
- StyleCop plugin removed (because obsolete)
- sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24

After project analysis, if an issue exists, then the analysis close and reopen the issue. You can see the following example:

1> sonar project task history:
[image]

2> initial issue creation and closed:
[image]

3> issue reopened and reclosed:
[image]

4> issue reopened:
[image]

### EDIT 2

There's a bug during the sonar scanner: **sometimes projects in the solution aren't analysed.**

Here are the parameters for the both build sonar step:

begin /k:"toto:FrontWebCore_Dev" /n:"FrontWebCore Dev" /v:1.0 /d:sonar.host.url=http://sonar:9000/ /d:sonar.scm.provider=tfvc

1> first build only 4 projects analysed...:

[image]

2> second build all 15 projects are analysed:

[image]